# Hair Image Texture is black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, image

So when I am using cycles in blender, every time I use an image texture for this model's hair, it turns out like this. He is supposed to be completely blonde and no matter what I add or manipulate in the nodes, it doesn't change so there is always this black in his hair.

Is there something I should be doing in particular or is it something else? Because it works for majority of the other models except a few that do the same thing, particularly the blonde ones or one's that have wavy hair.

[image]

These are the textures used for this model's hair

[image]

Thanks :) Btw I'm new to this site so sorry if I do something wrong! :/

Here
[image]

I tried to duplicate the question "How can I setup a Material in Cycles for Z-Transparency?" and this is what I got. It's still not right.
[image]

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your material's node setup?

Comment: The node setup for the image above is just simply the first image (hair _faded_straight blonde hair) and the displacement third image(hair_faded_straight grey coloured) and that's it. I've only recently started using cycles so I don't know how to use them properly yet. I don't have a file atm of my node "attempts" because I gave up, so I can't screenshot it but I pretty much tried everything available and it did nothing.

Comment: Where did you input the second file? The blueish one.

Comment: I've never used that one before. I've never known what it was for. I thought it was maybe volume but when I inputted it, it just made his hair blue like in the image and/or didn't make a difference to the black in his hair. I noticed it made his hair messier or scruffier looking but that's it.

Comment: It's a normal map. Its RGB data maps to the X Y and Z values of the direction of the normals. Try connecting it to the Normal input of the shader(s).

Comment: I did what you said but knowing me I probably did it wrong. Cycles really confuse me sorry! I'll put my setup in the question area because I don't know how to add it anywhere else. His hair just went kinda dark.

Comment: Well, I've only quite recently switched to cycles from blender internal myself, and I'll have to leave this to someone with more experience than I have.

Comment: Okay no worries. Thank's for your help anyways :)

Comment: I don't think Alpha to Displacement is right. Have you tried using the Color instead? Possibly with an RGB to BW in between.

Comment: Just tried it. Still no change :/

Comment: Does it need an alpha map?

Comment: Not sure. Explain it to me.

Comment: Cut the link between the image and transparency, you don't need the colour going into the transparency.

Comment: YES! It worked! Finally! *cries tears of happiness* Thank you!